# How to import "termcolor" function properly?

Tags: python-3.x, colors

I imported termcolor to my code and it didn't give any colors when i ran the code. The rest worked fine.

I have imported termcolor in powershell and it says "Requirement already satisfied".

```
from termcolor import colored

color = input("What colour would you like? ")

colored_ascii = colored(hello, color=color)
print(colored_ascii)
```

I expected the output to be colored, but it's always white(on blue background), which is the default in powershell.

Comment: Is `hello` a variable? `termcolor` (version 1.1.0) is working as expected in Ubuntu 18.04. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/OpceEpE

Comment: `termcolor` doesn't seem to work for me either (it seems to be a rather old package), but `colored` works, you could try if it also suits your needs https://pypi.org/project/colored/

Comment: hello is what i want to print, but the color is not working.